# Reverse lookup nested attributes in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code that to me is very ugly.  Is there a cleaner way to write this code?

```
  type Bar = String
  case class Foo(bars: List[Bar])

  def groupByBar(foos: Seq[Foo]) = (for {
    foo <- foos
    bar <- foo.bars
  } yield bar -> foo).
    groupBy {case (bar, foo) => bar}.
    map {case (bar, foos) => bar -> foos.map {_._2}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you want a function that takes a `List[Foo]` and returns a `Map[Bar, List[Foo]]` where each `Bar` from the `List[Foo]` is mapped the `List[Foo]` that contained it.

This can be done quite easily using `scalaz` and `foldMap`:

```
def groupByBar(foos: List[Foo]): Map[Bar, List[Foo]] = {
  foos.foldMap { foo => 
    foo.bars.foldMap { bar => Map(bar -> List(foo)) }
  }
}
```

Comment: What imports are needed for that to work, please? It doesn't compile for me with Scalaz 7 and the usual `import scalaz._; import Scalaz._`

Comment: Wouldn't that return tuple2[Bar,Foo]?

Comment: @ekaqu: you're right, I forgot the `Map` constructor. This should work with scalaz 7. I believe `foldMap` is imported from `scalaz.Foldable`.

Comment: Two small changes to the above will work: Switch from Seq to List (there is no Monoid[Seq]), and wrap foo in List.

Answer (score 0):

Using the core collections, it can be done a little more concisely (though not especially clearly) as follows:

```
def groupByBar(foos: Seq[Foo]) =
  foos.flatMap(f => f.bars.map(b => (b,f))).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```